# Magento2 After Create Category Oops, Sorry We Can't Find That Page

Tags: magento2.3.7

Magento2 After Create Category Oops, Sorry We Can't Find That Page

I despaired because of the category

I created a category and named it Test and in Url Key test-test and then I went to

Marketing and SEO & Search and URL Rewrites

and i have added custom Category Rewrite

and i add in Request Path test.html

and in Target Path catalog/category/view/id/3

and i make save and cache:flush and indexer:reindex

and i cleard the cache browser I don't know why the category does not work

i have magento 2.3.7 P4

the products work fine but category if i want to go to path in frontend not working

i get error page not found 404

not wroking if i go to path domain.com/test.html

or path catalog/category/view/id/3

I've tried everything